# Pip Install - "Invalid requirement"

Tags: python, pip

I run the following command in my terminal:

```
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'nose=1.3.7'
= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

requirements-dev.txt looks like this:

```
nose=1.3.7
pyflakes=0.9.2
pep8=1.5.6
```

Why am I getting this error? I'm not too familiar with the pip command.

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggested?

Comment: You are getting this error because *= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?*

Answer (score 7):

`pip` does not specify any behavior for `=` in its specification, rather `==` (which you intend) referred to as [version matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-matching), among others.

For your later use, all the currently available version specifiers as at version 8.1 are:

> version matching `==`
>
> Compatible release `~=`
>
> Version exclusion `!=`
>
> Exclusive ordered comparison `<` , `>`
>
> Inclusive ordered comparison `<=` , `>=`
>
> Arbitrary equality `===`